# com.mcruiseon.buseeta E/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve Lmy/library/class/file; annotation class 8906

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar, annotations

My library project starts like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetUserDomainOrGroupMasterResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class GetUserDomainOrGroupMasterResponse implements Serializable,
```

I have built a jar, and copied this jar to the libs folder of my android project using `android studio`.

My gradle file in my android studio project has

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

I also tried adding

```
compile files('libs/mylibrary.jar')
```

When I open the jar archive the class file is **RIGHT THERE**

Now, when I run my project I get a

> com.myapp.package E/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve Lmy/library/class/file; annotation class 8906

I have tried

1. compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile files('libs/mylibrary.jar')
2. compile files('libs/mylibrary.jar')

   3.
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

I have also tried building a `executable jar` for my jar file and still I get the damn `Error`

I dont get it. What am I missing here ?

**Edit**

I noticed that the app does not have any side effect due to this Error. In any case its a irritant. Please help me resolve this.

Comment: What library contains `@XmlRootElement`? Does you app have the dependency to it (via gradle or jar in libs)?

Comment: Would you provide answers to my questions, so I might guess what is the problem?

Comment: `jaxb-api` has the definition to `@XmlRootElement`

Comment: jaxb-api is not part of android. Do you pack your app with this library?

Comment: Is `jaxb` using annotations in runtime or it is doing code generation in compile time?

Comment: I have a jar that has this code with this annotation. These annotations are being used on the server side. I dont need them on the client (android) side.

Comment: This annotation has runtime retention https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.3u1/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html. So JVM is trying to find this annotation class anyway when you construct instance of this class

Answer (score 2):

`@XmlRootElement` annotation has retention `RUNTIME` in **jaxb-api**. This annotation should be available in runtime as normal classes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation).

Since your library compiled against **jaxb** it has a notion of this annotation, but it is not included and can not be found in runtime.

As a solution, you could add **jaxb** as compile dependency to your app (several Mb plus) or add just this annotation definition to your android project.